# The first result of ctime function is always a constant output

Tags: c++, function

I have tried many times using different datas, however, the result in the first line is always "Thu Jan  1 08:00:00 1970". Other results from this function are correct.
The following is the code:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<algorithm>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

struct data {
    time_t time;
    char url[50];
    char username[20];
};
int main()
{
    int lines;
    std::cin >> lines;
    data* ones = new data[lines];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        std::cin>> ones[i].time >> ones[i].url >> ones[i].username;
    }
    std::sort(ones, ones + lines);  //an operator overload is omitted here
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        std::cout<< ctime(&ones[i].time) << std::endl;
    }
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

The first line of output as well as the smallest result is always the same no matter what I input while other results are correct.
Input datas:

```
3

1503564157 http://bank.com/login wangwu 

1503564401 http://bank.com/logout wangwu 

1503544401 http://bank.com/pay lisi
```

Output:

```
Thu Jan  1 08:00:00 1970

Thu Aug 24 11:13:21 2017

Thu Aug 24 16:46:41 2017
```

What's more, the translater always warn me that " the function or variable may be unsafe..." so I can only add "#pragma warning(disable : 4996)". I cannot understand the reason for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `ones[i].time`? How is it initialized?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Unrelated: Include the C++ header `ctime` instead of the C header `time.h`

Comment: The value you pass first, is most likely a zero.

Comment: ... and you are in a locale with an 8 h diff to UTC.

Comment: @Evg"Ones" is structure array including "time_t time", "char url[50]"，"char username[20]".

Comment: @trawolf Instead of describing it in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62148544/edit) the question and put a [mcve] in it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried but it still doesn't work.l

Comment: @trawolf Are you saying that you tried to edit the question and put a [mcve] in it?

Comment: There is a bug in your program that causes one entry to have a `time` of zero. Unfortunately, the part of your program that creates these objects seems to be a carefully guarded secret.

Comment: @trawolf tl;dr; A [mcve] is the shortest program possible to reproduce the problem. We should be able to copy, paste and compile your code as-is - with no additions needed. Can you put such an example in your question?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I said that I tried the head file"ctime" but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @trawolf It was not clear which question you answered. What error do you get if you try `#include <ctime>`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The output is still incorrect after I add `#include<ctime>` instead of `#include<time.h>`.

Comment: Don't add one tiny snippet of code at a time, post a [mcve]. The bug is somewhere inbetween `data* ones = new data[lines];` and `std::sort(ones, ones + lines);`. (Or possibly in your `operator<`.)

Comment: @trawolf My comment about using `ctime` instead of `time.h` was unrelated to the problem you have. You will often see comments marked "_Unrelated:_" or similar which means that someone has spotted something that you should fix, but it's not related to the problem you describe.

Comment: It's much better after your last edit - but it's still not possible to compile it. Try compiling the code yourself before posting.

Comment: @trawolf This is the result when compiling your current code: https://godbolt.org/z/BvDjrW

Comment: ... and here's the same code with the minimum amount of changes that I would do: https://godbolt.org/z/byZzjZ